# While loop change variables

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to change the text in the variable after one round of the cycle.
Like first round of loop a="A", second round a="B".

```
a = ("A")
a1 = ("B")
a2 = ("C")
a3 = ("D")
a4 = ("F")

i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(a)
    a += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: Why don't use *cycle* from itertools module?  Like ```cycle('ABCDEF)``` is the best use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the values in an array and access the values:

```py
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

i = 0
while i<5:
    print(a[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing a by one (in the line a += 1) will increase the contents of the variable, not change the name. You should instead use an array like

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

and then iterate such as through

```
ans = a[i]
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lists in such kind of tasks:

```
a = "A"
a1 = "B"
a2 = "C"
a3 = "D"
a4 = "F"

values = [a, a1, a2, a3, a4] # This is the list of values that you could address by their index

i = 0
while i < len(values): # iterate while i is less than the amount of values
    print(values[i])
    i += 1
```

Read more about lists [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)